# How to localize DatePicker and TimePicker in WP8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, datepicker, timepicker

I am attempting to localize the DatePicker and TimePicker associated with the toolkit on WP7, but I am unsure of how to access the Header and the application bar texts. I have not been able to find any links showing methods of accomplishing these tasks. Are there any useful links or does someone have the source of how this many be accomplished?

Answer (score 2):

1. Easiest method to download Source and Samples of the latest version of the Toolkit (Nov 2011) which has by default localization for `DatePicker` and `TimePicker`.
2. Add the it as project reference to your solution.

If you have the Toolkit version prior to Nov 2011,

1. Again add it as Project Reference in your Solution
2. In side the project tookit in your solution. Add the necessary resx files. You can see there is a default Resources.resx file which has the English text for date pickers. Add the necessary resx files for other languages.

Comment: I did download the Nov release with source and added it as a reference to my project, but my DatePicker and TimePicker page titles and app bar icons do not translate accordingly? Also, I tried adding the ControlResources resx files to my solution directly and then building the solution, but once more the Title and app bar icons do not translate properly. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: App bar icons will not be translated. But the others will be. Have you included the necessary languages in the Supported culture?. Inside the LocalizedResources, you'l find the necessary resx right?. To which language are you trying to localize?

Comment: I believe I did everything correctly, and I am translating into all supported languages on WP7. I followed this tutorial http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff637520(v=vs.92) and when I change the display language all strings translate correctly except for the DatePicker and TimePicker strings.

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple: Parameter - Language. Xaml code:

```
<toolkit:DatePicker Language="ru-RU" Margin="-12, 0" Value="{Binding BirthDate, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Comment: Thanks I will look into this. I updated the name of my question to include WP8 now instead, it may be different I haven't had the chance to use the DatePicker yet.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative without modifying the XAML source is to modify the "HeaderTitle" TextBlock once the page loads.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Called from app.xaml.cs if the user navigates to the DatePickerPage
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="page">The page.</param>
    public static void DatePickerHook(PhoneApplicationPage page)
    {
        // Somehow modify the text on the top of the page...
        LoopThroughControls(page, (ui => {
            var tb = ui as TextBlock;
            if (tb != null && tb.Name == "HeaderTitle")
            {
                tb.Text = "<<Local Translation>>";
            }
        }));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Applies an action to every element on a page
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="parent">The parent.</param>
    /// <param name="modifier">The modifier.</param>
    private static void LoopThroughControls(UIElement parent, Action<UIElement> modifier)
    {
        int count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
        if (count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                UIElement child = (UIElement)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
                modifier(child);
                LoopThroughControls(child, modifier);
            }
        }
        return;
    }
```

Here's the link to the blog post that describes the modifications to app.xaml.cs also: http://blog.dotnetframework.org/2015/11/09/localise-datepicker-in-wp8-silverlighttoolkit-using-hooks/